# How to redirect default path '/' to '/home' in React Router v6. Current configuration does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm rendering nested routes with the parent route rendering some components I would like present in every page.

I want the Default component to render for every page and have `"/"` redirect to `"/home"`.
Currently, when I input my `"url.com/"`, the page does not redirect and displays an error fallback component.

Could someone please help me find a solution to and understand why the redirect is not working?

```
const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    element: <Default/>,
    children: [
      { path: '/', element: <Navigate to='/home' /> }, 
      ...otherRoutes
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 4):

The home path should be `"/"` instead of `"\"`. `\` is an escape character.

```
const publicRoutes = [
  {
    element: <Default />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/", // <-- here
        element: <Navigate to="/home" replace />
      },
      ...navbarRoutes
    ],
  }
];
```

[image: Edit how-to-redirect-default-path-to-home-in-react-router-v6-current-configur]

Comment: great catch Drew 

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my end. Fixed it in the post. My original code uses "/" and still does not redirect as it should

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone! I figured out why it wasn't working.
The current configuration was correct. It was a bug somewhere else in my code.

Comment: Give a proper justification otherwise somewhere in the code means ?